# Dynamic input not function the select dropdown php

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I'm trying to display the select dropdown in my dynamic input but I could not display.

This is my example image:

[This is the first dynamic input I display the select from my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrroj.png)

[In the second dynamic input the select dropdown not display from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Gjq.png)

And this is my code:

```
<form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])): ?>
                <div class="msg">
                    <?php
                        echo $_SESSION['msg'];
                        unset($_SESSION['msg']);
                    ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-select" name="pro_brandName[]" required>
                            <option disabled selected value="">BRAND NAME</option>
                            <?php
                            include_once("../function/brandlist.php");
                            ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>  
                        <td><input type="text" name="pro_Details[]" placeholder="DETAILS PRODUCT" class="form-control name_list" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" /></td>  
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-select" name="category[]" required>
                                <option disabled selected value="">CATEGORY</option>
                                <?php
                                include_once("../function/categorylist.php");
                                ?>
                            </select>    
                        </td>
                        
                        
                        
                        <td><input type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="PRICE" class="form-control name_list" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" /></td>  
                        <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="QUANTITY" class="form-control name_list" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" /></td>  
                        <td><input type="date" name="expiry_date[]" placeholder="EXPIRATION DATE" class="form-control name_list" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" /></td>  
                        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button></td>  
                    </tr>
                     
                </table>  
                <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="SAVE" />   
            </div>  
        </form>



<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select class="form-select" name="pro_brandName[]" required><option disabled selected value="">BRAND NAME</option><?php include_once("../function/brandlist.php"); ?></select></td><td><input type="text" name="pro_Details[]" placeholder="DETAILS PRODUCT" class="form-control name_list" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" /></td><td><select class="form-select" name="category[]" required><option disabled selected value="">CATEGORY</option><?php include_once("../function/categorylist.php");?></select></td><td><input type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="PRICE" class="form-control name_list" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" /></td><td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="QUANTITY" class="form-control name_list" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" /></td><td><input type="date" name="expiry_date[]" placeholder="EXPIRATION DATE" class="form-control name_list" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"../function/save_products.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```